# How to use JSON path extractor to pick the same value for 2 condition

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

I have a JSON response like this

```
Members":
[
    {
        "id":"ABC",
        "name":"XXXX",
        "XXX":"XXX",
        "XXXX":"XXXX",
        "Managers":
        [
            {
                "id":XYZ,
                "name":"XXX",
                "XXXX":XXXX,

            }
],
```

I need to get the value ABC and XYZ from the above response and I am using 2 JSON extractor to fetch the value and storing it in different variable.

JSON Extractor 1 expression:-

```
$..Members.[*].id
```

JSON Extractor 2 expression:-

```
$.Members..Managers.[*].id
```

But the above code picks the value from different arrays like sometime it picks the Members id as ABC but picks the Managers ID from different array. I want it to pick the value from same array value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use index option instead of `$..Members.[*].id` use `$..Members.[0].id` which will always use the same index

Comment: But that will ensure that all the threads are using the same value which is not the correct approach.

Comment: Please exemplify your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to extract first member and his first manager:

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON and configure it as follows:

   - Variable names: `memberId; ManagerId`
   - JSON Path expressions: `$.Members[0].id; $.Members[0].Managers[0].id`
   - Match No: `1; 1`
   - Default Values: `NOT_FOUND; NOT_FOUND`

     [image: JMeter JSON Extractor]
2. Refer `ABC` as `${memberId}` and `XYZ` as `${ManagerId}` where required. You can see JMeter Variables using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree Listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

   [image: JMeter Variables from JSON]